# Setting Pixels in Cocos2d-js - how to?

Tags: texture2d, cocos2d-js

My goal is to write directly to pixels in a texture/sprite, to be able to update the game's details.

I was successful in doing this in Cocos2d-x with C++ (sample code below).  The question is, "How can I do the equivalent in Javascript?"

```
//C++ WORKS:
board_texture= *sprite->getTexture();

// initialize pixels (array of GLubyte)
for (i=0 ; i<num_pix; i++){
    pixels[i] = (GLubyte) 0;
}

// editing colors at specific positions:
            pixels[i]=(GLubyte) 255; // r
            pixels[i+1]=(GLubyte) 0; // g
            pixels[i+2]=(GLubyte) 0;// b
            pixels[i+3]=(GLubyte) 255; // a

    board_texture.updateWithData(pixels,0,0,board_w,board_h);
    sprite->setTexture(&board_texture);
```

This runs extremely fast on an iPad updating a 400x400 texture easily at 60FPS.

I've looked at Cocos2d-JS, however, and can find NO equivalent working functions for "updateWithData".  I was able to get the texture2D into a local variable, but can find no way to update it's pixels (yet)

```
//JS does NOT work
var t;
t= this.map_sprite.getTexture(); // OK
// but does NOT allow me to updateWithData 
t.setTexture(pixels) // fails, with Invalid Native Format.  What's the proper format then?
```

Why? Cocos2d's developers are saying C++ is not supported in the future as much as Javascript (Cocos2d-js), as evidenced by the lack of JS support in the Cocos IDE.  So, since I'm just starting out, I figured, I should do it in JS, not C++.

Comment: I don't really know if this is actually possible. I know we can [get individual pixels in JS (for transparency comparison, for example)](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-get-single-pixel-of-sprite-with-cocos2djs-and-cocosbuilder/7250/5), but this is a really slow proccess. I think you are going to have to ask this on the [official forums' JS section](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/c/cocos2d-x/javascript) or in the [project's github page](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-js/issues).